# input routine using java api t24

Tags: java

I am trying to set a default value to a field using input routine in java aAPI development IN T24.

I am using `setvalue()` method for a specific field but it is not working.
How can i do it?

```
@Override
public TValidationResponse validateRecord(String application, String currentRecordId, TStructure currentRecord,
            TStructure unauthorisedRecord, TStructure liveRecord, TransactionContext transactionContext) {
       
    AccountRecord acc=new AccountRecord(currentRecord);
    //NOT WORKING
    TField mnemonic= acc.getMnemonic();
    mnemonic.setValue("abc");
```

Comment: What is type of `TField ` ??

Comment: Tfield offers getter and setters for values and error.;    i used also acc.setMnemonic("abcd") and didn't work @VishwaRatna

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you've shown, it seems that you are using the validateRecord Method instead of defaultFieldValue, hence the issue. Note that each method has a different exit points that can be found in their respective EB.API record.

You may use defaultFieldValue, to default a value in any T24 fields. You may refer on below line of codes.

```
@Override
public void defaultFieldValues(String application, String recordId, TStructure record, TStructure lastLiveRecord) {

AccountRecord acc=new AccountRecord(record);
acc.setMnemonic("ABC");
record.set(acc.toStructure());

}
```